# Does CSS transition perform bettern than DOM animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I was running something which does number scrolling using [ScrollerJS](http://scrollerjs.pixelstech.net/). It supports two modes : CSS transition and DOM animation. When I was using the DOM animation mode, I find sometimes the scrolling is not smoother than that of CSS transition.

So I am wondering whether CSS transition performs better than DOM animation generally? Is there any proof or testing that shows this?

CSS transition : CSS3 `transition/transform` property which transforms an element

DOM animation : Traditional DOM animation which changing the CSS `top` property continuously.

Comment: To supplement some of the answers you're getting, it might be a good idea to read this resource as well: https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/ (Granted, this was written a little while ago, so things may have changed in how browsers handle this.)

Comment: @Serlite This article seems indicate that CSS transition performs poorer...

Comment: @PixelsTech it depends on the library, the type of animation, and how well it's implemented. In your case, the authors of ScrollerJS have told you which is the better implementation (when available), so you should probably trust them. Also, your edit makes it even easier to answer. CSS `transform` will *always* beat animating `top` - you need to use far more sophisticated techniques to even approach the performance of CSS

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes. Doing it in CSS allows the browser to optimize it, e.g. using hardware acceleration.

If you manipulate the DOM, the browser generally has to re-render the content, which is usually slower.

DOM manipulation is typically used to support older browsers where CSS animation is not supported (or poorly implemented).

From http://scrollerjs.pixelstech.net/#about

> If CSS transition is supported in a browser, CSS transition will be
>   the preferred option for animation.
>
> If in old browsers where CSS transition is not supported. DOM
>   animation will be chosen automatically.

However, note that as usual, things are never completely straightforward, and no generalization is completely true... There are javascript animation libraries out there that can rival or sometimes even outperform CSS-based transitions/animations, and they are usually more flexible. Here's some light reading:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation

https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Comment: What if I don't have a powerful GPU?

Comment: You don't need to have a powerful GPU - the kind of operations you're talking about here won't tax even 10-year-old hardware.

Comment: but please note my added caveat above.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't too hard to answer.

A DOM animation uses your CPU for it's calculations and since an animation is quite heavy on the CPU it'll sometimes 'lag' which is when you see artefacts on the screen.

CSS3 transitions however are able to use hardware acceleration which uses the GPU of your computer (if it has one ofc :D). Since your GPU is much stronger and better at doing things like animating, you'll barely notice any lag if any.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not easy to answer because in different cases some kind of animation performs better than the other.

I think this [article](http://greensock.com/css-performance) could be more than interesting if we are talking (seriously) about performance between CSS and DOM animations.

If you are going to work a lot with animations and you are worry about the performance I suggest to try a more professional library like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/), they also have a scroll plugin.